# JSP unbalanced bracket for if condition

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have added below to my jsp but it says, unbalanced at line x which breaks scope 'tag:html:form'
This line number refer to <%}else{ %> which i dont find any problem?
What i am missing here?

```
<%if(request.getAttribute("fileUploadFlag").toString() != null){ %>      
  <html:form action="goAction" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">      
<%}else{ %>       
  <html:form action="goAction" method="POST">      
<%} %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's upset because the `<html:form>` tag isn't being closed. You might be better off putting your if/else just around the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute. Or defining encType as a variable using your if/else, and have the form underneath

```
<%String encType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; // I assume...%>
<%if(request.getAttribute("fileUploadFlag").toString() != null){ %>      
    encType = "multipart/form-data";
<%} %>
<html:form action="goAction" method="POST" enctype="<%encType%>"
```

Comment: It would be even better to remove the scriptlets and use jstl